# Does MER of a given product (say ETF) ever go down?

Tags: investing, etf, fees

If I buy a new product with relatively high Management Expense Ratio (MER), can that MER be theoretically/technically reduced in the future, for example when the product gains more and more popularity?

Comment: Note that you absolutely shouldn't plan on this happening, of course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, some mutual funds may have the expense ratio decline as the fund gains more assets. Look at the history of the Vanguard 500 Index as an example over the years where it used to be about 20 basis points but has dropped a few as the assets have gotten very large.